# postgreSQL max select depending on groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, filter

I am facing a particularly difficult (for my skill level) select query.
I have some data in a database which are as such:
4 columns (maleName/femaleName/size/id).
The column data are more or less self-explanatory. I have a male's name, a female's name a size and an id (which only gets values 1 or 2) accordingly to each column. The only problem is that male and female names (as couples) appear more than 1 time.

```
    Database example.
# | MaleName | FemaleName | Size | ID
    1 - John - Mary - 9 - 1
    2 - Nick - Stacey - 6 - 1
    3 - Mike - Rachel - 2 - 1
    4 - John - Mary - 3 - 2
    5 - Mike - Rachel - 20 - 2
    6 - Nick - Stacey - 13 - 2
    etc...
```

What I need is a Select query which will return the max(size) of each couple and the ID it belongs to...

```
Result example.
# | MaleName | FemaleName | Size | ID
1 - John - Mary - 9 - 1
2 - Nick - Stacey - 13 - 2
3 - Mike - Rachel - 20 - 2
```

What I 've done so far is this:

```
select a.Mname,a.Fname,a.size
from mytable a , mytable b
where a.id=b.id and 
a.size in (select max(a.size) from mytable a , mytable b where a.id=b.id)
group by a.Mname, a.Fname, a.size;
```

I don't know if I am close , or totally wrong. This returns 1 result though. It might need some tweaking or total re-writing. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance guys!

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I solve these problems using `row_number()` because this works in many databases:

```
select mname, fname, size, id
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by t.mname, t.fname order by t.size desc) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

The function `row_number()` assigns a sequential number to rows within a group.  In this case, all rows with the same pair of names will be numbered (the `partition by` clause).  The numbering starts with the row with the biggest size (the `order by size desc`).  You want the biggest size, so that has a sequence number of 1.

Postgres also supports `distinct on` syntax, which can do the same thing, but that is quite database-specific.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately I have tried what you gave me and although it works partialy (groups the couples etc.) it fails to filter out the couple with the smaller size number.

Comment: @GeorgeElementSotiriou . . . Do you have the `where seqnum = 1` in your query?  Does your partitioning clause only contain the two names?

Comment: Tha answer is yes to both. Also I had already corrected the "mytable t" part that you edited some minutes ago since I found out it should be like that by myself. Still partitioning is made I have my identical "couples" descending by size one after another but it fails to rule out the dublicate couple with the lowest size number. Sorry for making your life hard...! :(

Comment: @GeorgeElementSotiriou . . . In that case, I would guess that the names are *not* identical on the two rows -- there are some hidden characters or spaces that may not be visible.

Comment: That may be tha case because those names come from 2 different excel files (thus the ID 1 or 2) which are maintained by 2 different people. I'll check this out and give feedback as soon as possible... I've checked about such differences and haven't seen none with "naked eye". I'll try some copy/pasting now and some manual work.

Comment: @GeorgeElementSotiriou . . . Do a `group by` on the table by first name and last name and see if you are getting two different rows.  That should be using the same mechanism as the `partition`.

Comment: You were right I deleted some extra spaces and it performed BRILLIANTLY! Thank you, you are my God!